# Get property value and convert class type to boolean

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, getvalue

I have following piece of code:

```
 ClassName class = new ClassName();

 var getValue = GetPrivateProperty<BaseClass>(class, "BoolProperty");

 public static T GetPrivateProperty<T>(object obj, string name)
    {
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        PropertyInfo field = typeof(T).GetProperty(name, flags);
        return (T)field.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
```

Now when I get an InvalidCastException in the return statement that he can not convert the object with type System.Boolean to the type ClassName.
BaseClass has the property. ClassName inherits from BaseClass. In have to access all properties from the "ClassName" Class. Since this property is private, I have to access it directly over the BaseClass. This works but I crashes because the property has the return value boolean.

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly said, I did understand nothing. Can you try to rephrase your question so that everybody else understands your problem? :)

Comment: Ok I tried :) Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the property of type `T` and the return value should also be of type `T`? I don't believe that.

Maybe this will help:

```
var getValue = GetPrivateProperty<bool>(class, "BoolProperty");

public static T GetPrivateProperty<T>(object obj, string name)
{
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    PropertyInfo field = null;
    var objType = obj.GetType();
    while (objType != null && field == null)
    {
        field = objType.GetProperty(name, flags);
        objType = objType.BaseType;
    }

    return (T)field.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Please see the changes of `<BaseClass>` to `<bool>` and `typeof(T).GetProperty` to `obj.GetType().GetProperty`.

Comment: This does not work because then I get a null value in field. I have to access the BaseClass directly.

Comment: @Jackson30 Oh yes of course. GetProperty will not recognize base types. Sorry. I changed the code.

Comment: I changed that to: return (bool) field.GetValue(obj, null); - does this work correctly?

Comment: @Jackson30 ??? That does work if you only access bool-Values. My method should work for every other type too. But yes it will work in your case. The only other thing you have to do is to change the return value of `GetPrivateProperty` from `T` to bool.

Comment: Did that. Now it works fine! Thank you very much for your help!